# Is there a way to add an Outlook additional mailbox store?

Tags: windows, powershell, outlook, mapi

I am trying to create a script that will recreate the outlook profile. Currently I am looking for a way to add additional mailboxes via the Outlook com object, since not all mailboxes can be added via automapping.

Unfortunately I have not found an approach on the internet. Is there any solution at all?

Comment: please take the tour and this question probably needs to go some place else. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Object Model does not expose that functionality. You can either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) to add a properly configured instance of the `"EMSDelegate"` MAPI service, or use [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) - it exposes [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).[Stores](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostores.htm).`AddDelegateExchangeMailBoxStore` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for creating mail profiles. You may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook was built. See [Programmatically create a profile in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/how-to-programmatically-create-a-profile-in-outlook) for more information.